# C++ - using std::list, how do you print a linked list of an object's private members?

Tags: c++, list, class, linked-list, private

It works for when I make Unit's members public. Changing the variables to private, how do I access/print them?

My professor hasn't taught the method of iterating through a linked list of objects (in this case ) and how to access that object's private members. Do I do implement getters and setters? I'm really lost since I'm pretty new at linked lists and using the list library.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Unit {
private:
    string name;
    int quantity;
public:
    Unit(string n, int q){
        name = n;
        quantity = q;
    }
};


void showTheContent(list<Unit> l)
{
    list<Unit>::iterator it;
    for(it=l.begin();it!=l.end();it++){
        //
        cout << it->name << endl;
        cout <<  it->quantity << endl;
//        cout << &it->quantity << endl;  // shows address
    }
}

int main()
{
    // Sample Code to show List and its functions

    Unit test("test", 99);

    list<Unit> list1;
    list1.push_back(test);
    showTheContent(list1);

}
```

Comment: This doesn't really have anything to do with the `std::list`. A class private and public members work the same no matter where they are stored or how you try to access them. Surely you have learnt something about what private and public do in a class?

Comment: To overcome `private`, You need to implement either getters or provide other means to access private members for `name` and `quantity` or make `showTheContent` a friend. Google it.

Answer (score 1):

The private specifier's goal is to prevent the access to the members from outside of this class. Your design of the `Unit` class is ridiculous because you hide the members from everybody and you don't use them inside of this class either.

You may open the access the members, you may add getters/setters, implement the Visitor pattern -- there are many options. The simplest is to open the access (make everything public): you should judge based on the task that your professor gave you.

By the way, in your `showTheContent` function you are making the full copy of the list, which you are probably not planning to do. Use a const reference instead:

```
void showTheContent(const list<Unit>& l)
```